# modal dont open in codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a modal but it opens when i´m in the base domain, for example:

The modal opens in the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

but not open in the

[www.example.com/index.php/cart/index](http://www.example.com/index.php/cart/index) and I dont know why

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4>Select your language</h4>                       
            </div>
            <!--<section>-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><img width=128px height=128px src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/323/323329.png" alt="" class="img-responsive none" style='object-fit: contain'/></a>
                    <p>English</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img width=128px height=128px src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/323/323329.png" alt="" class="img-responsive none" style='object-fit: contain'/>
                        <p>English</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img width=128px height=128px src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/323/323329.png" alt="" class="img-responsive none" style='object-fit: contain'/>
                            <p>English</p>
                            </div>
                <div class="tab_img">
                    
                        <div class="container" style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
                                
                                <div class="overlay">
                                </div>
                            </a>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            <!--</section>-->
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

the script that activate the modal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
            event.preventDefault();
    
    
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
        });
    });
</script>{/literal}
{literal}<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you checked whether the script that load in the homepage is the same in the cart/index. can you also post how you trigger this modal in the cart/index? Thanks

Comment: `{literal}<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(".scroll").click(function(event){  
    event.preventDefault();
  
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
   });
  });
</script>{/literal}
{literal}<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
</script>{/literal}`

Comment: @RicardoMartins Please edit your post with the javascript code that you added in the comment.

Comment: I already updated with the script

Comment: @Ricardo Martins please show us your problem with picture??

Comment: When you click on the button to trigger the modal, check your browser console bar for errors or other information.

Comment: Check all the source files like bootstrap css and js files and jquery. I think these files are missing in your cuuent page. Or you can check errors in console then do accordingly.

Comment: it is not loading the css files in the www.example.com/index.php/cart/index, i dont know the reason why.It load in the www.example.com but not in the www.example.com/index.php/cart/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your **base_url()** in the config.php.
Probably the problem is that you are not loading the css correctly.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked in the Routes.php?

```
$routes->get('/', 'Cart::index');
```

hope this will solved your problem.

Comment: When I add that to my router.php it just give me a codeigniter error

Comment: I think i may found the problem, it is not loading the css files in the www.example.com/index.php/cart/index, i dont know the reason why